# Compact database file like solution for storing small information with php

Tags: php, database, storage

I am developing a facebook app using php SDK, my app is small and simple meant for a community project and its database contains only one table with 6 columns and hardly 10-20 lines of record.

I am using heroku for hosting my app which doesn’t provide a direct database hosting capability. Plus I think storing such small information in a total separate database server would not be very resource efficient.

**I am looking for some simple solution for it, something like a compact database file which I can just upload to the directory and my code can get connected to it and retrieve information from it using a sql query**, a simple and efficient solution. Or any other nice suggestions to handle this.

My app doesn’t require storing any information to the database on runtime but only retrieval from already existing information, simple something like:

`Select * from table where column LIKE %value%`

Kindly guide me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: How about [sqlite](http://php.net/sqlite)? `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is the tool for the job; there is a [built-in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) (for 5.0.0 >= PHP version < 5.4.0) [PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlite.php) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and nice reply. just one thing, how to add data in it, does it provides an IDE to store inital data and then make a compact file of it?

Comment: @Maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers

Comment: @Maven - check the docs or do a web search `:)`. You connect to it, create tables, and do SQL ops much like any other database in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (php functions [here](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)).

Answer (score 0):

How about SQLlite?
http://www.sqlite.org/
http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php